# Check if one column value is in another column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

I want to compare one column with another column in the same dataframe. Not just between adjacent value but iterating through every value in Col1 and see if it exists in Col2 values.

```
Col1        Col2    exists
cat         pig     true
a           cat     false
pig         b       true
mat         axe     false
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df["exists"] = df["Col1"].isin(df["Col2"])`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Col1_value = set(df['Col1'].unique())
df['exists'] = df['Col2'].map(lambda x : True if x in Col1_value  else False)
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.